# Show/hide issue - shown divs are moving place

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/RfkCw/

That's my code, you cannot see the error there but I assume many will know what I mean.

The answers are in order of course and they move slightly down each time like they aren't fully hidden.

How can I rectify this?

Comment: You assume many of us will know what you mean? I don't think so. Wheres the problem exactly?

Comment: Can you specify what is the functionality you want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, the problem is quite hard to explain without seeing it and for some reason jsFiddle does not replicate it. I'm showing/hiding divs. 4 divs to be exact and when I click to hide the top div and show the div below, it shows it as if it comes in below the top div, literally. So on the screen you can see the divs that you unhide as if they are moving position all the time.

Comment: Is there any possibility of other code that is influencing the behavior?

Comment: Possibly, but not that I know of, I cannot honestly say I would know how to tell.

Answer (score 1):

When you inspect the page, pay attention to margins, padding, height, and width (before and after the question is hidden).  It's possible that your cms  is dynamically modifying the styles (with javascript) when it notices a display change.